# Is there a way to put a VS Code snippets file in a non standard folder and have VS Code use it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, version-control, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I want to create a standard VS Code snippets file for my team. We use Perforce for version control and I'd like to create a snippet file in our project folder and point VS Code to it. I just want people to be able to sync up and have them just have updated snippets.

Answer (score 0):

I think Project-level snippets will do what you want:

> **Project level snippets**
>
> Snippets can now be scoped to a project and
> shared with your team. Simply use the **Preferences: Configure User
> Snippets** command or create *.code-snippets file in the .vscode folder.
> Project snippets work just like other snippets, they show up in
> IntelliSense and in the Insert Snippet action where they now have
> their own category

**More info:** https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_28#_project-level-snippets